# Graphic card definition

Tags: graphics

how to download and install graphic card definitions , GEFORCE CUDA
Thants :) . Iam new to Linux and i don'r know how to deal with compressed files .
I've downloaded a CUDA Definitions but I didn't know what to do next.

Comment: Are you asking the same question as [For CUDA Installation on Ubuntu14 which .deb file to select](http://askubuntu.com/questions/473295/for-cuda-installation-on-ubuntu14-which-deb-file-to-select)?

Comment: Hi, which version of Ubuntu are you using and what is the model of your graphics card ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the extension of file that you downloaded or you can just download it like that:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```